# Batch to copy a file to a folder and only ONE subfolder deep

Tags: batch-file, copy, cmd, subdirectory

I have this batch file now that copies `example.jpg` from `C:\Temp` to the Test-folder and all its subfolders.

I would like it to copy the file only 1 subfolder deep in the Test-folder.
For example copy the picture to `Test\subfolder` but NOT to `Test\subfolder\subfolder2`

```
@echo off
for /r "C:\Temp\Test" %%f in (.) do (
    copy "C:\Temp\example.jpg" "%%~ff" > nul
)

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET destroot=c:\temp
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ( ' dir /ad/b "%destroot%"' ) DO ECHO COPY "c:\temp\example.jpg" "%destroot%\%%i\"
```

Simply shows what the batch PROPOSES to do. Remove the `ECHO` keyword to activate the copy and add `>nul` to suppress the "copied" message

Answer (score 1):

Don't use recursion if you want to go only 1 level deep. Try this instead:

```
@echo off

set src=C:\Temp\example.jpg
set dst=C:\Temp\Test

copy "%src%" "%dst%" >nul

for /d %%d in ("%dst%\*") do (
  copy "%src%" "%%~fd" >nul
)
```